# NDK not configured. Download it with SDK manager when compile flutter app

Tags: flutter

Today when I compile the flutter(2.5.1) app, show error like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':system_clock'.
> NDK not configured. Download it with SDK manager. Preferred NDK version is '21.1.6352462'. 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have already checked the NDK configuration and make sure the version is installed:

[image]

why the project prefer another version of NDK version? what should I do to configure the right version of NDK?

Answer (score 0):

Just check '21.1.6352462' in NDK and press ok.

It'll do the rest.

Or check this issue

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53657